# how to convert the information from row to column in R

Tags: r, reshape

I have a dateset named "df":

```
df <-  structure(list(outcome = c("cg00000029", "cg00000029", "cg00000029", 
                              "cg00000108", "cg00000108", "cg00000108"), 
                             pval = c("0.63", "0.91", "0.01","0.09", "0.55", "0.23")), 
                            .Names = c("outcome", "pval"), class = "data.frame",row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

[image]

How could I convert it into dataset named "df1"?

```
df1 <-  structure(list(outcome = c("cg00000029", "cg00000108"), 
                  pval_1 = c("0.63", "0.91"), 
                  pval_2 = c("0.01","0.09"), 
                  pval_3 = c("0.55", "0.23")), 
                  .Names = c("outcome", "pval_1", "pval_2", "pval_3"), class = "data.frame",row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `tidyverse` approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(outcome) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = id, values_from = pval, 
              names_glue = "{.value}_{id}")

# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   outcome [2]
  outcome    pval_1 pval_2 pval_3
  <chr>      <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
1 cg00000029 0.63   0.91   0.01  
2 cg00000108 0.09   0.55   0.23
```

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` option using `dcast`

```
> dcast(setDT(df), outcome ~ paste0("pval_", rowid(outcome)))
Using 'pval' as value column. Use 'value.var' to override
      outcome pval_1 pval_2 pval_3
1: cg00000029   0.63   0.91   0.01
2: cg00000108   0.09   0.55   0.23
```

Comment: Hi ThomasIsCoding, could you send the code, please? Thank you.

Comment: @akrun haha, my bad. Thank you for reminder!

Comment: @OliviaWang See my update. I forget to attach my code, sorry.

Comment: Thank you so much! Very helpful!